# Convert geodata from .rdb and .mpr files

Tags: convert, oracle-dbms

I've got an COM-server and activeX client (looks like delphi app), that display some geodata.
Data stores in files with .rdb and .mpr extensions.

I find out that rdb is oracle database file format. There is no running oracle server on my machine, but application still works.

Is there any tools which could help me convert this data to another preferred format (.shp or .tab or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are using a scopira server (research council of canada). You can find more info here...
[Scopira](http://www.scopira.org/index.html)

It utilizes rdp files which are not of oracle decent. The format is described more here...
[RDP format](http://www.scopira.org/rdp/tutorial/node3.html)

As far as converting to a mainstream GIS it looks like these are a text file so you may be able to decipher the format and use something like FME (safe.com) to read the txt into you appliication or to workbench for translation. [Custom format capability](http://www.safe.com/technology/documents/technical_briefs/Custom_Formats_Tech_Brief.pdf)